# Need Help Looping Through URLs with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the names of all companies [listed on this site](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%20%3D%2010-12b%20OR%20form-type%3D10-12b%2Fa&start=241&count=80&first=2009&last=2018).  Each page (14 in total), shows the name of 80 companies.  Each URL has a **start=241&count=80&first=2009&last=2018** at the end, where start is the first row of the page.  I'm trying to loop through every 80 companies, which will loop through each page, and scrape the names of the companies.  However, everytime I try, I get this error on the second time through the loop:

```
File "beautiful_soup_2.py", line 10, in <module>
name_table = (soup.findAll('table')[4])
File "C:\Users\adamm\Downloads\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

However, if I remove the list and manually enter a URL where **start=81, 161, 241**, etc., the result returns the list of companies on the page.

My code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for x in range(1,1042,80):
sauce = ('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%20%3D%2010-12b%20OR%20form-type%3D10-12b%2Fa&start={}&count=80&first=2009&last=2018'.format(x))

source_link = urlopen(sauce).read()
soup = soup(source_link, 'lxml')

name_table = (soup.findAll('table')[4])
table_rows = name_table.findAll('tr')

for row in table_rows:
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

This is driving me crazy, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is not working in the above code. seems alright.

Comment: When I loop through the urls, I get the error listed on the second loop.  But when I enter each url individually, it works.